# Update my database - Failure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb

Update: I debugged it several times and it seems that the 'UpdateUserDetails' function was fine, but I think the problem is in this line (within UpdateUser function):

```
var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq("ID", input.ID);
```

---

I have a website (I have yet to upload it online), in which I use MongoDB on local host. I have USER SYSTEM (includes Login, Registration..). I tried to add an option to edit any registered user manualy by the admin, but I keep failing with updating the database with the new 'version' of the user.

The relevant code is attached..

~ The update function:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateUser(User input)
    {
        // var a = input.ID;
        var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq("ID", input.ID);
        var update = Builders<User>.Update
        .Set("FirstName", input.FirstName)
        .Set("LastName", input.LastName)
        .Set("Phone", input.Phone)
        .Set("Email", input.Email)
        .Set("Password", input.Password)
        .Set("Permission", input.Permission);
        DBManager.UpdateUserDetails(filter, update);
        ViewBag.Update = "Update successful";
        return RedirectToAction("UsersList");
    }
```

~ My DBManager class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
using SurffingSite.Models;



namespace SurffingSite.DB
{
    public class DBManager
    {
        static MongoClient client;
        static IMongoDatabase DB;
        // Constractor
        static DBManager()
        {
            client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            DB = client.GetDatabase("HELLOSTACKOVERFLOW");
        }
        // Method to get list of all users//
        public static IMongoCollection<User> GetUsersCollection()
        {
            var collection = DB.GetCollection<User>("User");
            return collection;
        }

        internal static object GetCollection<T>(string v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

                                           //User Method  //

        // Method for adding new user
        public static void AddNewUser(User user)
        {
            var collection = DB.GetCollection<User>("User");
            collection.InsertOne(user);
        }
        //Get user email.
        public static User GetUserEmail(User input)
        {
            User email = DBManager.GetUsersCollection().Find(user => user.Email == input.Email).FirstOrDefault();
            return email;
        }

        //Get user passsword.
        public static User GetUserPassword(User input)
        {
            User password = DBManager.GetUsersCollection().Find(user => user.Password == input.Password).FirstOrDefault();
            return password;
        }
        //User login verification 
        public static User UserVerification(User input)
        {
            // try get user by email
            // if user exist than check if the password is correct if not than return null
            User UseVar = DBManager.GetUserEmail(input);
            if (UseVar != null && UseVar.Password == input.Password)
            {
                return UseVar;
            }
            return null;
        }
        //Update User details
        public static void UpdateUserDetails(FilterDefinition<User> filter, UpdateDefinition<User> update)
        {
            var collection = DB.GetCollection<User>("User");
            collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
        }

        //Products Method's//

        // Adding product into DB
        public static void AddProduct(Products product)
        {
            var collection = DB.GetCollection<Products>("Products");
            collection.InsertOne(product);
        }
        public static IMongoCollection<Products> GetProductsCollection()
        {
            var collection = DB.GetCollection<Products>("Products");
            return collection;
        }
        // Find product in DB by ID
        public static Products FindProductsById(Products input)
        {
            Products searchedProd = DB.GetCollection<Products>("Products").Find(product => product.Id == input.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            return searchedProd;
        }
        //Update product
        public static void UpdateDetails(FilterDefinition<Products> filter, UpdateDefinition<Products> update)
        {
            var collection = DB.GetCollection<Products>("Products");
            collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);

        }

                                          //Orders//

        // This method will return all exist orders 
        public static IMongoCollection<Orders> GetOrdersCollection()
        {
            var collection = DB.GetCollection<Orders>("Orders");
            return collection;
        }
        //Place an new order
        public static void AddOrder(Orders order)
        {
            var collection = DB.GetCollection<Orders>("Orders");
            collection.InsertOne(order);
        }
        // Search for all user orders
        public static List<Orders> FindUserOrders(User user)
        {
            List<Orders> searchedorders = DB.GetCollection<Orders>("Orders")
                .Find(order => order.User.ID == user.ID).ToList<Orders>();
            return searchedorders;
        }
    }
}
```

~ The User model:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SurffingSite.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        [Required]
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId ID { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("FirstName")]
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("LastName")]
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Phone")]
        public String Phone { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Email")]
        public String Email { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Password")]
        public String Password { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Permission")]
        public string Permission { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I think the failure is within the 'Filter'...

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: "i keep failing" means what? You're getting an error? Or it just never updates? What debugging have you done to look into this? It's not clear what you're trying to say, please clarify the details

Comment: No error. It doesn't update the user with the new details. I was trying various options to figure out what the problem is.. I think the problem is within the 'Filter' but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: have you set breakpoints to assess the contents of your variables as the code progresses, and check that the desired code actually executes with the expected variable values? If so, and you're still not sure what to do, please edit the question to confirm what you've discovered, and provide sample data

Comment: I updated some stuff, I hope it makes mroe sense

Comment: ok so you think you found a line which is the problem...so as I asked, please verify the data. is the value of `input.ID` set to what you expected when you run the code? You haven't mentioned anything about it. That's the first thing to check.